# Mlflow authorization with spnego

Tags: authentication, kerberos, mlflow, spnego

I saw this topic about Kerberos authntication - https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/2678 . It was in 2020 . Our team trying to do authentication with kerberos by spnego. We did spnego on nginx server and it is fine - and get code 200 when we do curl to mlflow http uri . BUT we can't do it with mlflow environment variable .

The question is - Does mlflow has some feature to make authentication with spnego or not? Or it has just these environment variables for authentication and such methods :

- MLFLOW_TRACKING_USERNAME and MLFLOW_TRACKING_PASSWORD - username and password to use with HTTP Basic authentication. To use Basic authentication, you must set both environment variables .
- MLFLOW_TRACKING_TOKEN - token to use with HTTP Bearer authentication. Basic authentication takes precedence if set.
- MLFLOW_TRACKING_INSECURE_TLS - If set to the literal true, MLflow does not verify the TLS connection, meaning it does not validate certificates or hostnames for https:// tracking URIs. This flag is not recommended for production environments. If this is set to true then MLFLOW_TRACKING_SERVER_CERT_PATH must not be set.
- MLFLOW_TRACKING_SERVER_CERT_PATH - Path to a CA bundle to use. Sets the verify param of the requests.request function (see https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/). When you use a self-signed server certificate you can use this to verify it on client side. If this is set MLFLOW_TRACKING_INSECURE_TLS must not be set (false).
- MLFLOW_TRACKING_CLIENT_CERT_PATH - Path to ssl client cert file (.pem). Sets the cert param of the requests.request function (see https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/api/). This can be used to use a (self-signed) client certificate.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the source code. No, the `mlflow.utils.rest_utils.http_request` function doesn't support SPNEGO in any way – it can only send HTTP 'Basic' or 'Bearer' authorization headers.

However, it should be relatively easy to change it to generate a 'Negotiate' header using [pyspnego](https://pypi.org/project/pyspnego/), or even to use [requests-gssapi](https://pypi.org/project/requests-gssapi/) given that it already uses Requests internally:

```py
# For Linux:
import requests_gssapi
# For Windows:
#import requests_negotiate_sspi

def http_request(...):
    ...
    if not auth_str:
        # For Linux:
        kwargs["auth"] = requests_gssapi.HTTPSPNEGOAuth()
        # For Windows:
        #kwargs["auth"] = requests_negotiate_sspi.HttpNegotiateAuth()
    ...
```